# Is the sixed field of a DS record protocol?

Tags: layout, dnssec

Can some tell me what the layout is of DS record for DNSsec. A specialy the naming

If you look at this DS record:

```
231.72.212.in-addr.arpa.        3600 IN DS      45767 8 2 93f383a81ff2c124bdd395f51e58b88317cb8852facd93d3f6f30efdd2afa5b8
```

fieldsnames :

1. Hostname
2. ttl
3. ?? how is IN called
4. Record type in this case DS
5. keytag
6. Algorithm
7. Digest Type
8. Digest Field

I am not sure of my self  about field 6 is this protocol or NOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKe i found finaly the correct RFC : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034

I updated the exampel accordenly